# Converting Nested XML to csv using python for any XML file

Tags: python, xml, pandas, csv

I'm trying to convert a nested XML file into csv format and trying to develop a code in a way that it should be able to read any XML file. So whenever the structure of XML file changes, the same python code should be able to flatten the nested XML and convert it into the csv format.
For this use case, python code should be dynamic and it should generate structured csv file.
Is there any way to identify its root and the child values by using loop so that while parsing the nested XML file , it can identify columns and its values and will generate the csv file without missing any of the columns. No matter how much nesting is there in the XML file it should give me the structured csv.
Below you can see the sample XML for which I'm trying to find the approaches for the logic explained above.
It would be great if anyone knows any way for the above logic using python.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<items>


-<item type="donut" id="0001">

<name>Cake</name>

<ppu>0.55</ppu>


-<batters>

<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>

<batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>

<batter id="1003">Blueberry</batter>

<batter id="1003">Devil's Food</batter>

</batters>

<topping id="5001">None</topping>

<topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>

<topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>

<topping id="5007">Powdered Sugar</topping>

<topping id="5006">Chocolate with Sprinkles</topping>

<topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>

<topping id="5004">Maple</topping>

</item>


-<item type="donut" id="0002">

<name>Raised</name>

<ppu>0.55</ppu>


-<batters>

<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>

</batters>

<topping id="5001">None</topping>

<topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>

<topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>

<topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>

<topping id="5004">Maple</topping>

</item>


-<item type="donut" id="0003">

<name>Buttermilk</name>

<ppu>0.55</ppu>


-<batters>

<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>

<batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>

</batters>

</item>


-<item type="bar" id="0004">

<name>Bar</name>

<ppu>0.75</ppu>


-<batters>

<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>

</batters>

<topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>

<topping id="5004">Maple</topping>


-<fillings>


-<filling id="7001">

<name>None</name>

<addcost>0</addcost>

</filling>


-<filling id="7002">

<name>Custard</name>

<addcost>0.25</addcost>

</filling>


-<filling id="7003">

<name>Whipped Cream</name>

<addcost>0.25</addcost>

</filling>

</fillings>

</item>


-<item type="twist" id="0005">

<name>Twist</name>

<ppu>0.65</ppu>


-<batters>

<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>

</batters>

<topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>

<topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>

</item>


-<item type="filled" id="0006">

<name>Filled</name>

<ppu>0.75</ppu>


-<batters>

<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>

</batters>

<topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>

<topping id="5007">Powdered Sugar</topping>

<topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>

<topping id="5004">Maple</topping>


-<fillings>


-<filling id="7002">

<name>Custard</name>

<addcost>0</addcost>

</filling>


-<filling id="7003">

<name>Whipped Cream</name>

<addcost>0</addcost>

</filling>


-<filling id="7004">

<name>Strawberry Jelly</name>

<addcost>0</addcost>

</filling>


-<filling id="7005">

<name>Rasberry Jelly</name>

<addcost>0</addcost>

</filling>

</fillings>

</item>

</items>
```

Comment: what is the expected output `df`?

Comment: yes, that will work. We can also read csv file using pandas (df=pd.read_csv)

Comment: The [python] tag is used, but there is no Python code in the question. "It would be great if anyone knows any way for the above logic using python" is not a problem statement.